# Celery error callback not getting called

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery application where I must execute a task **A**, then a group of tasks **B** when it's done ; and finally a task **C** if everything went right.
Tasks **A** and **B** are likely to throw exceptions.

I have followed the code in [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#error-handling) (where they use `on_chord_error`), and the callback is not getting called for group of tasks **B** *unless* I only put one argument to the error task.
I need to know which exception was thrown, so the 3-arguments alternative is what I need. How can I have it working ?

Here is a simplified example of my code :

```
@celery.task()
def task_a(throw_exc=False):
    print('first task')
    if throw_exc: raise KeyError

@celery.task()
def task_b(i):
    print('intermediate task %d' % i)
    if i == 2: raise ValueError

@celery.task()
def task_c(*args):
    print('Final task with args %s' % args)

@celery.task()
def error_task3(request, exc, traceback):
    print('An error occured')
    print(exc)

@celery.task()
def error_task1(*args):
    print('An error occured')
    print(exc)

def call_tasks(throw_exc):
    first = task_a.si(throw_exc).on_error(error_task3.s()) # WORKING
    g = group(task_b.si(i) for i in range(5))
    final = task_c.s().on_error(error_task3.s()) # NOT WORKING
    final2 = task_c.s().on_error(error_task1.s()) # WORKING

    (first | g | final).delay()  # Callback never called
    (first | g | final2).delay() # Callback called with the task id as a string
```

Did I misunderstood the documentation, or is it an error ?